# ES6 Classes Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, ecmascript-6

I have the following Class:

```
export class PlatformIcon {

    constructor() {
        this.platform = '';
        this.userAgent = '';
    }

    get icon() {
        console.log('logging');
        switch (this.platform.name) {
            case 'www':
                return 'fa fa-desktop';
                break;
            case 'mobi':
                return 'fa fa-mobile';
                break;
            case 'ios':
                return 'fa fa-apple';
                break;
            case 'blackberry':
                return 'icon-blackberry';
                break;
            case 'android':
                return 'fa fa-android';
                break;
            default:
                return '';
        }
    }
}
```

When instantiating, the getter seems to go into an infinite loop, i.e. the `console.log()` statement gets logged over and over again.

Comment: why do you have `case 'ios'` twice? I geuss the last is supposed to be android.

Comment: How are you calling the property? [Works fine here](http://bit.ly/1QdMMcr)

Comment: Also, you don't need to put `break` statements after `return`. `return` itself immediately finish the function and go out of the `switch`